# Selenium cookies? addCookie

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cookies

Can I log in on youtube.com with cookies in selenium?
Let's say I want to test youtube app. I got my cookie by typing document.cookie in console.
How do I add this cookie to my selenium session?
I just can't find an understandable example on browser.manage().addCookie().
Here's one:

```
browser.manage().addCookie('testcookie', 'Jane-1234')
```

So, how do I change it? Like so?:

```
browser.manage().addCookie('youtube.com', my_cookie)
```

Comment: What data you got in console ?

Comment: A string, that represents my cookie